# Scroll effect with specific content in android

Tags: android, list, scrollview

I want to implement scrolling in android with following effect:

1. Screen 1

[image: Initial position]

2. Screen 2

[image: Intermediate position]

3. Screen 3

[image: Final position]

Basically I want to show the album with its list of songs and download start from half of the screen.
I should be able to scroll through the list. The first part should get scrolled upto top of the screen. Once it reaches to top of the screen the part show change its look and remaining part should be scrolled.

Comment: Do you want to implement a bottom to top transition? Post some codes  that you tried and ask for help, rather than asking for codes.

Comment: I tried using listview header and list inside scrollview but could not achieve.

Comment: Can you please give any idea regarding this effect.

Comment: What type of effect do you want? Page slide from bottom to top ?

Comment: I want to scroll the list such a way that the top view should stop at top of the screen and the list should scroll. You can clearly see in 3 images

Answer (score 0):

You can implement bottom to top transition using the following library :

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

In case slide the listview from bottom to top and use listview background as semi transparent, so you can have previous activity in background.

Another solution would be to implement bottom to top transition animation like this:

pull_up_from_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
android:fromYDelta="100%"
android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

push_out_to_bottom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="0%"
android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

Java code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Alok thanks for your help. But I dont want to do transition rather I want to scroll it using finger touch. But while scrolling the top item which is separated using a light line should stop scrolling at top and should be fixed there. And the song list should scroll till it ends. Please help in that.